# Entity Framework Id auto incrementing

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Have a problem with incrementing.
I created a new object and tried set it into my DB I received an error of data violation. The index in table wasn't increased (Id=0). 
Id - set as primary key in SQL table and the `StoredGeneratedPattern` property of field "Id" in EDM set as "Identity" so, obviously, it must be incremented automatically.

```
public void AddPhone(UserPhone phone)
{
    context.AddToUserPhone(phone);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I can't understand why.

Comment: Did the new object get saved?

Answer (score 5):

Entity Framework does not automatically increment IDs. That's the database's job. Set the ID column on the database table as an IDENTITY column so that it will auto-increment. Then you should find that after you `SaveChanges()` the phone's ID property will have been set to the value the database chose for it.