# Primary keys created by Entity Framework are not auto-incrementing

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-migrations

Let me show the error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table
>   'TCCDatabase.dbo.ProfessionalModels'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails.

I got this error when trying to insert n record into my database using a database created by my EF application.

I think it's happening because my database Id column is not auto-incrementing.

[image: Identity field]

My question is: Why are my Id Columns not auto-incrementing?

One of my models:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TCCApplication.Models
{
    public class ProfessionalModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Profession { get; set; }

        public UserAddressModel UserAddressModel { get; set; }
        public UserAccountModel UserAccountModel { get; set; }

        public ProfessionalModel() { }
    }
}
```

My context class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using TCCApplication.Models;

namespace TCCApplication.EntityFramework
{
    public class TCCDatabase : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<UserAccountModel> UserAccountContext { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProfessionalModel> ProfessionalContext { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserAddressModel> UserAddressContext { get; set; }

        public TCCDatabase()
        {}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProfessionalModel>().Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccountModel>().Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserAddressModel>().Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The definition of your pk should set identity specification to yes and autoinc even without the fluent configuration. What happens if you remove the fluent configuration and build a new migration?

Comment: @user3411327 It creates an empty migration

Comment: Identity must be set on table create. If this did not happen there is an explanation how to intoduce it later [here](http://romiller.com/2013/04/30/ef6-switching-identity-onoff-with-a-custom-migration-operation/).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989627/entity-framework-id-auto-incrementing) question, it seems like it is not EF's job to auto-increment the ID, but rather the database's job. The column that should increment needs be set as the identity.

[image]